# How is the HTTP version of a browser request and the HTTP version of a server response determined?

Tags: browser, webserver, http

Can anyone verify if my assumptions are correct?

I think most popular browser (Chrome, Firefox, ...) as a standard send requests with HTTP/1.1 in each request line.

I think whether or not a HTTP/1.1 response is given  is determined by the web server (E.g. a specific version of Apache, Nginx, ...) that hosts the web application. I assume all modern web servers now have HTTP/1.1. If the web server doesn't support HTTP/1.1 I think it will interpret the HTTP/1.1 request as if it was HTTP/1.0 and give a HTTP/1.0 response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe you have the gist of it with one exception:

1. Each request specifies the HTTP protocol level.
2. The web server decides what to do differently (if anything) based on a request with up/down level versioning.
3. HTTP/1.1 is well established and any decent server will support it.

The version matching however is not quite as adaptive as you suggest though. If the client request specifies a MAJOR version that the server does not support, the server responds with…

> 505 HTTP Version Not Supported

In your case, 1.1 and 1.0 share a major version, so (with some exceptions) your assumption is correct, the server will try to respond to a down level request.

For more info on http response codes, see [RFC 2616 section 10](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and [section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.1)