# How does a web server communicate HTTP/2 support to a client?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, wireshark

I built a nodeJS HTTP2 server on my localhost: 127.0.0.1:8443. Went to wireshark and selected the loopback adapter to capture the traffic when i hit the server from my chrome. I dont see the server specifying in the communication steps whether it supports HTTP2. Chrome just identifies HTTP 1.1 as the protocol of the communication. I want to understand when would the server specify the protocols it supports and why communication in my case is not happening over HTTP2 when i created a nodeJS server as HTTP2?

I went through this: [How is the HTTP version of a browser request and the HTTP version of a server response determined?](https://superuser.com/questions/670889/how-is-the-http-version-of-a-browser-request-and-the-http-version-of-a-server-re) but its not helping.

[image]

Comment: If you want HTTP/2 you _must_ use TLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

For **secure** connections, the intent to do HTTP/2 is negotiated during the TLS negotiation, via TLS-ALPN. Then after TLS negotiation completes, both sides exchange HTTP/2 Connection Prefaces and continue to do HTTP/2 from that point on.

For **insecure** connections, the intent to do HTTP/2 is not negotiated at all any more (and maybe never was). The client (browser) just has to somehow already know that the server supports HTTP/2, and once the insecure TCP handshake completes, the client should start the connection with an HTTP/2 Connection Preface, which the server should respond to with its own HTTP/2 Connection Preface, and both sides should continue to do HTTP/2 from that point on.

### Long Answer

This is covered in the HTTP/2 specification, the latest version of which, as of this writing, is RFC 9113. You specifically want to look at Section 3, "Starting HTTP/2".

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9113#starting

[Note: An earlier version of the HTTP/2 spec provided a way for insecure connections to upgrade from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2, but it was never widely deployed and is now deprecated. I don't know which browser versions or server versions may have supported it, but it involved the client making an HTTP/1.1 request with some special headers communicating that it's capable of HTTP/2 and would like the server to upgrade the connection to HTTP/2 if possible, and then the server would respond with an "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" response and then treat the rest of the connection like HTTP/2 (i.e. by exchanging HTTP/2 Connection Prefaces with the client, etc.)]

So if you want to make an insecure HTTP/2 connection, the browser just has to somehow already know that the server supports HTTP/2, and it needs to simply establish the TCP connection and then start with an HTTP/2 Connection Preface.

In the case of TLS-secured `https://` URIs, the client specifies that it wants to use HTTP/2 via TLS Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation (TLS-ALPN), as specified in [RFC 7301](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301.html).

Once TLS negotiation completes, the client and server each send an HTTP/2 Connection Preface.

From your packet trace screenshot, it doesn't look like your browser is trying to do HTTP/2 at all. Even though your port number 8443 suggests an alternate port 443 suggesting TLS, I don't see TLS happening, so I presume TLS-ALPN isn't happening, but maybe it's happening but your screenshot doesn't show it. Your browser also doesn't start the connection with a HTTP/2 Connection Preface, it starts it with an HTTP/1.1 connection without even the now-deprecated Upgrade headers. So you may need to figure out how to tell your browser to treat your server as HTTP/2, and that may involve enabling TLS and TLS-ALPN on your server, so that your browser can learn of the HTTP/2 support via TLS-ALPN during the TLS negotiation.

Comment: It might be noteworthy that insecure HTTP/2+ is basically dead, browsers don't support it.